# EDX keeps marking my code incorrect. mit 6.001x week 2

Tags: python, edx

## in this while loop I am finding out the updated balance and making updated balance my new balance.this is a brief overview of problem:          Write a program to calculate the credit card balance after one year if a person only pays the minimum monthly payment required by the credit card company each month.

The following variables contain values as described below:

balance - the outstanding balance on the credit card

annualInterestRate - annual interest rate as a decimal

monthlyPaymentRate - minimum monthly payment rate as a decimal

For each month, calculate statements on the monthly payment and remaining balance. At the end of 12 months, print out the remaining balance. Be sure to print out no more than two decimal digits of accuracy

```
balance = 42
months = 0

monthlypaymentrate = 0.04
annualinterestrate = 0.2
MIR = annualinterestrate / 12

while months != 12:
    minimummonthlypay = monthlypaymentrate * balance

    Monthlyunpaidbalance = balance - minimummonthlypay

    Updatedbalance = Monthlyunpaidbalance + (MIR * Monthlyunpaidbalance)

    balance = Updatedbalance

    months += 1
if months == 12:
    print("Remaining balance :", round(Updatedbalance, 2))
```

Comment: i don't wanna flag this question , but explain about the problem , what does it want ?

Comment: Not really sure what's supposed to be going on here, but you're not incrementing any values inside your `while` loop. `minimummonthlypay` _et al_ just keep taking on the same values 12 times rather than building on the previous iteration of a loop. The only thing that increments (with `+=`) is `months`